# Twitter Bloodhound results from function

Tags: typeahead, bloodhound

I'm using TypeAhead with Bloodhound to try achieve cacheable results returned from a function.

The thought behind is as follows:

- TypeAhead calls bloodhound
- Bloodhound calls the function to return results
- Bloodhound caches those results, and returns them to TypeAhead
- TypeAhead displays those results
- User appends to input, so TypeAhead calls BloodHound to search through the cached results instead of another call to the DB.
- User clears textbox, TypeAhead and BloodHound resets

Currently, I have TypeAhead calling directly from the results function every time the user changes the input:

```
jQuery(element).typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true, // This is to bold words that match the query
    minLength: 3
}, {
    name: "result",
    displayKey: "value",
    source: function (query, callback) {

        typeaheadResults(query, callback);

    }
});
```

However, I want BloodHound to retrieve the results... I haven't got much experience in it, and have tried the following:

```
var bhResults = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.num); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: // What do I do here? function typeaheadResults needs the 'query'
});
```

The typeaheadResults does quite a lot, so I can't simply use BloodHound's `remote` procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue too, I fixed it like this:

```
var bhResults = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.num); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: []
});

typeaheadResults(/* you don't need a query with bloodhound */, function(result){ bhResults.add(result); });

bhResults.initialize();

jQuery(element).typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true, // This is to bold words that match the query
    minLength: 3
}, {
    name: "result",
    displayKey: "value",
    source: bhResults.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: I'm confused by this code; not sure where you're referencing `typeaheadResults` considering the `source` is set to the adapter, which has a local array.

Comment: @pixelbobby **To directly answer your question; Line 7.**

In the question he passes an function as a source which calls typeaheadResults.

With bloodhound you don't pass a filtering function as a source but an array, otherwise there wouldn't be a reason to use bloodhound. So if the source is an array you can directly pass it as a local on the Bloodhound constructor options, if it's an network resource which doesn't support queries you can just call it anywhere and insert it to the bloodhound in the async callback.

Just like what I did in line 7.